# Is drupal a framework

Tags: drupal, frameworks

I am new to Drupal. I never used any framwork . I googled definition for framework. Many of the those definition suits to drupal-Its my opinion. So someone clarify my doubt. Is drupal a framework or not.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Drupal is a CMS (Content Management System).

Comment: Good. You've applied a definition of a word to a specific example. Be sure of yourself :)

Comment: @Sann i know it is Web CMS. During evaluation review in my office my tech lead asked me can we say  drupal is a framwork ,if yes, give proper explanation. I said i didnt use any framwork so i am not sure about it is a framwork

Comment: This is more of a semantics question. Anything that provides a layer of abstraction over the underlying code is a framework. Now you decide whether it is framework or not.

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia calls [Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal) a [Content Management Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_framework) (CMF).

> A **content management framework (CMF)** is a system that facilitates the use of reusable components or customized software for managing web content. It shares aspects of a web application framework and a content management system (CMS).

So yes, I would consider Drupal a "framework", as well as a CMS. It's designed to be a typlical CMS that allows non-programmers or web-developers to add and manipulate content. But also one that is very flexible and modular, so that you can customize it to do new things.

The reason I would call it a framework, is because it provides a lot of the typical framework-like things, such as database abstraction, user/session handling, etc.  If you compare some of Drupal's features like those to some of the big PHP frameworks, like CodeIgniter, I think you'll call it a "framework" too.